# Bootstrap CSS video backgrounds

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, video, responsive-design

I am currently using bootstrap on my site and have a responsive background image. This is done in the CSS file for my custom bootstrap theme. I know you cannot add MP4 video to the background element. What would be the best way for me to implement a video instead of the "closer.jpeg" image I have in the CSS code below?

As a followup. Is it also possible to auto play and loop on mobile?

```
    .intro {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 100px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: url(../img/closer.jpeg) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: http://demosthenes.info/blog/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<video id ="myVideo">
    <source src='video.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
    [video fallbacks here]
    [image fallback here]
<video>
```

CSS

```
#myVideo {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    ect.
}
```

Comment: Thank You SO Much for your fast feedback!